# Do I really need RRAS for serving a PPTP connection?

Tags: windows-server-2003, rras, pptp

Setting up PPTP has been a pain so far in Windows Server 2003.

I've already tried creating a new network connection, which creates some kind of network adapter for "Incoming connections", which appears to be the PPTP connection I want to connect to.

For some reason, the TCP/IP port 1723 would simply not appear, despite the connection being there.

I then decided to move onto RRAS, although it's complaining about ICS still being enabled (which seems to be a common problem for people, although a common solution is missing).

My question is this: which option am I supposed to be pursing? Should I be creating that PPTP listener with the network connection wizard, or using RRAS? It seems everyone is using RRAS, but I'd rather use a more simpler functionality, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the RRAS server, as the server will assign static IP addresses for VPN connections / will use DHCP for that. I'd also suggest disabling the firewall altogether, configure the PPTP service and then, if everything works, reenable the firewall. Note also that RRAS Server has its own firewall configuration, for both incoming and outgoing connections.

You can use Wireshark / Microsoft Network Monitor to check what port numbers the RRAS server actually uses.